# Thread cannot access the object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invalidoperationexception

I declared a field:

```
WriteableBitmap colorBitmap;
```

Then I created a simple thread which does something:

```
private void doSomething()
{
    // ... bla bla bla
    colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(/* parameters */);
    myImage.Source = colorBitmap; // error here:S
}
```

In Windows_Loaded event I declared and started a new thread:

```
private void window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doSomething));
    th.Start();
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't change myImage's source. I've got an error like:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I tried to use Dispatcher.Invoke, but it didn't help...

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    myImage.Source = colorBitmap;
});
```

I was searching for some answers, but never found the case exactly as mine. Could any1 help me to understand how to solve problems like this (I've had the same problem recently, but I couldn't call the method, because other thread owned it).

Comment: Well, off the top of my head, I guess this is WPF or Silverlight?  If I recall correctly (which I rarely do!) you can't instantiate a new `WriteableBitmap` on a background thread (for some silly reason).  Not sure why it wouldn't work after dispatching it to the main thread.  Maybe try `myImage.Dispatcher.Invoke` instead of `Application.Current.Displatcher.Invoke`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855308/asynchronous-operations-on-writeablebitmap for example. It's a special case - if you see the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx then the explantion is `When updates are sent to the rendering thread, the rendering thread copies the changed rectangles from the back buffer to the front buffer. The rendering system controls this exchange to avoid deadlocks and redraw artifacts, such as "tearing".'

Comment: myImage.Dispatcher.Invoke - same error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You can't access the `WriteableBitmap` from another thread that is different than the one who created it. If you want to do that, you need to freeze your bitmap by calling `WriteableBitmap.Freeze()` first
2. You can't access `myImage.Source` in a thread that is not the dispatcher thread.

This should fix both of these two problems:

```
private void doSomething()
{
    // ... bla bla bla
    colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(/* parameters */);
    colorBitmap.Freeze();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        myImage.Source = colorBitmap;
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
Note that this approach allows you to create and update your bitmap wherever you want in your thread. Once the bitmap is frozen, it can no longer be modified in which case you should just trash it and create a new one.

On a side note, if you wish not to block your thread updating `myImage.Source` use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`

Comment: Ok, it worked. There's no error now. But how to edit colorBitmap when it's frozen? How to unfreeze it?