# Fast multithreaded image processing, not so fast

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, image-processing, c++-cli

I'm creating a function which does some intense calculations for every pixel. Small laptops might not be able to work properly when using this function. I've never used threads to increase processing speed, but I don't think I'll be able to manage without them.

I thought it might be good idea to let one thread do all odd rows, and one thread the even rows. I created a little WPF app to test it out. It's a window with an image as background that changes from black to green. After some time it starts all over again. During every pixel update a mathematical function is executed.

Even though I hoped for a dramatic increase of speed it was pretty disappointing, can someone tell me how to optimize multithreaded image processing?

This is the code.

```
#define MULTITHREADED
#include <cmath>
#include "bitmap.h"//Based on WriteableBitmap, used this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855308/asynchronous-operations-on-writeablebitmap/5292315#5292315

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Threading;

public ref class TestWindow : Window
{
public:
    TestWindow(void) : _isActive(true)
    {
        _bm = gcnew Bitmap(1000,1000);
        ImageBrush^ ib = gcnew ImageBrush(_bm->bitmap);
        ib->Stretch = Stretch::Fill;
        this->BeginInit();
        this->Background = ib;
        this->Height = 300;
        this->Width = 300;
        this->EndInit();
        this->Loaded += gcnew RoutedEventHandler(this, &TestWindow::onLoaded);
        this->Closing += gcnew CancelEventHandler(this, &TestWindow::onClosing);
    }

    void onClosing(Object^ sender,CancelEventArgs^ e)
    {
        //Let the threads know the window is being closed.
        _isActive = false;
#ifdef MULTITHREADED
        //Give the threads a chance to terminate properly.
        _t0->Resume();
        _t1->Resume();
#endif
    }

    void onLoaded(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e)
    {
#ifndef MULTITHREADED
        _d = gcnew DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan(1),DispatcherPriority::Background,gcnew EventHandler(this,&TestWindow::sDispatchFunc),Dispatcher);
        _d->Start();
#else
        _t0 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this,&TestWindow::threadFunc));
        _t1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this,&TestWindow::threadFunc));
        _d = gcnew DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan(1),DispatcherPriority::Background,gcnew EventHandler(this,&TestWindow::mDispatchFunc),Dispatcher);
        _d->Start();
#endif
    }

#ifdef MULTITHREADED
    void mDispatchFunc(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        //Prepare the image for pixel access.
        _bm->lock();
        //Run the threads.
        if(_t0->ThreadState == ThreadState::Unstarted){//If one of the threads is unstarted, start them both.
            _t0->Start(_t0);
            _t1->Start(_t1);
        }else if(_t0->ThreadState == ThreadState::Suspended){//If one of the threads is suspended, restart them both.
            _t0->Resume();
            _t1->Resume();
        }
        //Wait for the threads.
        while(_t0->ThreadState != ThreadState::Suspended || _t1->ThreadState != ThreadState::Suspended){}
        //Place the new image.
        _bm->unlock();
        dynamic_cast<ImageBrush^>(this->Background)->ImageSource = _bm->bitmap;
        //Do everything over again if the window is still active.
        if(_isActive)
            _d->Start();
    }

    void threadFunc(Object^ sender)
    {
        //Determine which thread this is.
        uint8_t tid;
        if(dynamic_cast<Thread^>(sender) == _t0)
            tid = 0;
        else
            tid = 1;
        //Prepare the variables to avoid calculations in the loop.
        int w = _bm->width;
        int h = _bm->height;
        uint8_t* p;
        //This loop will stay active as long as the window is opened.
        while(true){
            //Determine where the thread should start.
            p = _bm->backBuffer + w * 4 * tid;
            //Change the image color.
            for(int y = tid; y < h; y += 2){
                for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
                    float y = cos(12.34) + sin(56.78) * sqrt(tan(0.9f));//Different calculations each test.
                    (*(p + 1))++;
                    (*(p + 3))++;
                    p += 4;
                }
                //Skip a row.
                p += w * 4;
            }
            //Give the image time to render.
            Thread::CurrentThread->Suspend();
            //If the window has been closed, stop the thread.
            if(!_isActive)
                return;
        }
    }

#else
    void sDispatchFunc(Object^ sender,EventArgs^ e)
    {
        //Prepare the image for pixel access.
        int w = _bm->width;
        int h = _bm->height;
        _bm->lock();
        uint8_t* p = _bm->backBuffer;
        //Change the image color.
        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
                float y = cos(12.34f);//Different calculations each test.
                (*(p + 1))++;
                (*(p + 3))++;
                p += 4;
            }
        }
        //Place the new image.
        _bm->unlock();
        dynamic_cast<ImageBrush^>(this->Background)->ImageSource = _bm->bitmap;
        //Do everything over again if the window is still active.
        if(_isActive)
            _d->Start();
    }
#endif

private:
    Bitmap^ _bm;
    DispatcherTimer^ _d;
#ifdef MULTITHREADED
    Thread^ _t0;
    Thread^ _t1;
    Thread^ _t2;
#endif
    bool _isActive;
};

[STAThread]
int main(void)
{
    System::Windows::Application app;
    app.Run(gcnew TestWindow);
}
```

These were the results I got under four different circumstances with Visual Studio in Debug mode:

1. no calculations per pixel.
2. cos(12.34f) per pixel.
3. cos(12.34f) + sin(56.78f) per pixel.
4. cos(12.34f) + sin(56.78f) * sqrt(tan(0.9f))

   ```
               Thread count  |  1        2
   Calculation               |
   __________________________|___________________
   1.                        |  2        17
   2.                        |  35       34
   3.                        |  67       62
   4.                        |  131      73
   ```

Is there a way to make the multithreaded version also work faster with less complicated functions?

Thank you.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that different cores do not share the L1 cache, so if different threads are working on the same general region of memory then you'll get lots of stalls as the cores lock each other out and the cache lines try to synchronize. Instead of farming out odd and even lines try splitting the image in half to reduce the chance of two cores hitting the same cache line.

Comment: You have *three* threads burning core, one is not doing anything useful but wait for the other two in a hot wait loop.  Use Join().  You are going to be memory-bus bound unless you let the threads do real work.  False sharing does look a bit remote.

Comment: @MarkFeldman: Thanks for the response. I tried it out and got the following results. 16 - 42 - 67 - 113. This is actually slower than what I originally had. I wanted to update the post, but for some reason I can't edit it. Calculation 4 for two threads was 103 and not 73 by the way, so the difference wasn't that big.